# build2 build different configurations

Tags: c++, build2

I created a default `build2` executable,

```
bdep new -t exe -l c++,cpp hello
```

edited the `hello.cpp`,

```
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
  using namespace std;

#ifdef NDEBUG
  cout << "Debug: off\n";
#else
  cout << "Debug: on\n";
#endif
}
```

created two configs (debug and release),

```
cd hello/
```

```
bdep config create ../hello-debug @debug cc config.cxx=g++ config.cxx.coptions=-g
```

```
bdep config create ../hello-release @releasecc config.cxx=g++ config.cxx.coptions=-O3
```

and initialized both.

```
bdep init @debug @release
```

I then run

```
bdep update @debug
```

and when I run the program I get `Debug: on`.

But now I want to build the executable in release mode

```
bdep update @release
```

but I still get the `Debug: on` output.

How do I switch configurations in `build2`

Answer (score 1):

`NDEBUG` is a standardized preprocessor flag which you are not adding to 'release' configuration.

This can be done by adding `config.cxx.poptions=-DNDEBUG` to your configuration.

```
bdep config create ../hello-release config.cxx.poptions=-DNDEBUG ..
```

See more info here https://build2.org/build2-toolchain/doc/build2-toolchain-intro.xhtml